#  Can someone explain how do we implement simple key/value stores with mysql?

Tags: database, nosql, key-value-store

http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/06/18/the-software-behind-facebook/:

> Facebook uses MySQL, but primarily as
>   a key-value persistent storage, moving
>   joins and logic onto the web servers
>   since optimizations are easier to
>   perform there (on the “other side” of
>   the Memcached layer).

Can someone explain how do we implement simple key/value stores with mysql? Is it simply a table with bigint as primary key + a single column of `LONGTEXT` ?

Comment: Which part is your actual question? Title says "what exactly is a simple key/value store" yet you seem to be asking why facebook uses MySQL in this way.

Comment: ok its actually 2 questions. i will put the other question in another post. edited question.

Comment: I am sure facebook has their key-value store in MySql due to historical reasons, not because it is a nice thing to do.

Comment: WTF? Subject closed while I was writing a long response? And not a real question? It's a damn good one! WTF?

Comment: For an alternate perspective, see ["The Mythical Business Layer"](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Mythical-Business-Layer.aspx)

Comment: @Alexander help me vote to reopen thx

Comment: @Kev i've edited the question. it's now a valid and powerful question..

Answer (score 1):

The starting point should really be "is your data relational?"
If so, use a relational db!

Key-value is a great solution for non-relational data, but if your data is relational, use SQL and be done with it.

Comment: yes the data is relational. but facebook is using key-value for their relational data.

Comment: Facebook is not a normal case.  Your business is not Facebook.  Your project is not Facebook.  For normal cases, if your data is relational, use a relational db.  To do it like Facebook does (just because FB does it that way) is premature optimization.

Comment: i find "premature optimization" becoming a buzzworld red flag whenever someone tries to learn something these days. Did i say i'm changing my database or anything? did i even say i HAVE a database or something? read my question again. i'm trying to learn something USEFUL bro.

Comment: You have changed your question.  The original question seemed to suggest that you felt that everything you had ever learned about relational databases was wrong b/c Facebook does it a different way.

Comment: perhaps it seemed that way to you. but take a look at your answer and tell me how does it even answer the question ? (even if you use the unedited question, your answer doesn't answer it too)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes, a key/value store is just that, you store a key and a value associated with that key. And you query based on the key.

The big advantages you get from this is,

- Scalability. You can now easily distribute your data across many(thousands) machines. This is something traditional RDBMS is not good at, joins and acid guarantees across many machines is either impossible or very very slow.

Facebook also have a lot of data that doesn't fit the relation model that ordinary RDBMS uses, namely graphs. That means they query/store/handle the graph nature of the data themselves instead of handling with SQL.

The cost of doing it that way is complexity, and often you have to give up a few points of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties.

The rest of us, that's not facebook/google/linkedin/etc. that only need to handle sites with up to just a few million users can usually just stick to using a traditional database.

Comment: isn't simply serializing objects and storing them in a datastore without worrying about it's data structure, and unserializing it whenever i need it much simpler than the traditional approach?

Comment: @jaytufch Is it ? It doesn't sound easier if you also want to compute sums, averages. Or if you want to list all purchases of a customer the last month. Or if you want to relate 2 records on several different fields. Or if you want atomic updates.